# How to calculate the deflection of GFC under Macro Fibre Composite load?

Tags: classical-mechanics, piezoelectric

I have this 85x14x0.3mm MFC(Macro Fiber Composite) bonded to GFC(Glass Fibre Composite)200x85x2mm. When MFC is powered up GFC sheet undergo deflection. I only know how to calculate deflection from static loading but when it comes to MFC the loading on GFC could change depending on given amount of voltage. The MFC applied stress on to GFC causing it to deflect.

MFC Shear Modulus is 5.5GPa
MFC Free strain per volt is 0.9ppm/V